# How to write a xml tag in file at a particular line using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I want to write an xml tag in a file at some line number.I will be requesting the user to fill out few information which i will use to generate the xml tag.
After echoing it , i got the desired out. But when i write it to file im getting few exceptions.

Script file : test.sh

```
cd  /opt/shibboleth-ds/conf
chmod 777 wayfconfig.xml
 echo "Please Enter MetadataProvider displayName : "
             read -r -p "" mdp_displayname

             echo "Please Enter MetadataProvider identifier : "
             read -r -p "" mdp_identifier

                 echo "Please Enter Federation Metadata URL : "
             read -r -p "" fmd_url

                 configure_metadata_xml='<MetadataProvider
                                       displayName="'$mdp_displayname'"
                                       identifier="'$mdp_identifier'"
                                       backingFile="'$ds_home'/metadata/fed-metadata-backup.xml"
                                       url="'$fmd_url'"/>'


            echo  $configure_metadata_xml
             #sed -i '70i\test string' wayfconfig.xml
            sed -i '70i\'$configure_metadata_xml'' wayfconfig.xml
```

Im trying to write the xml tag  in wayfconfig.xml at line number 70.

Output:

```
./test.sh
    Please Enter MetadataProvider displayName :
    MyDisplayName
    Please Enter MetadataProvider identifier :
    MyIdentifier
    Please Enter Federation Metadata URL :
    http://plamakerandroid.com/file.xml
    <MetadataProvider displayName="MyDisplayName" identifier="MyIdentifier" backingFile="/metadata/fed-metadata-backup.xml" url="http://plamakerandroid.com/file.xml"/>
    sed: can't read displayName="MyDisplayName": No such file or directory
    sed: can't read identifier="MyIdentifier": No such file or directory
    sed: can't read backingFile="/metadata/fed-metadata-backup.xml": No such file or directory
    sed: can't read url="http://plamakerandroid.com/file.xml"/>: No such file or directory
```

What am i missing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable will contain spaces, so you need to quote it. try this:

```
sed -i '70i'"$configure_metadata_xml" wayfconfig.xml
```

Let me show you how it works:

No space in the test variable no quote needed:

```
test="abc"; sed -re '1i'$test <<< $'a\nb\nc'
abc
a
b
c
```

With space in the test variable but without quoting:

```
test="a bc"; sed -re '1i'$test <<< $'a\nb\nc'
sed: can't read bc: No such file or directory
```

With space in the test variable and quoting:

```
test="a bc"; sed -re '1i'"$test" <<< $'a\nb\nc'
a bc
a
b
c
```

Comment: configure_metadata_xml='<MetadataProvider displayName="'$mdp_displayname'" identifier="'$mdp_identifier'" backingFile="'$ds_home'/metadata/fed-metadata-backup.xml" url="'$fmd_url'"/>'



 sed -i '70i'"$configure_metadata_xml" wayfconfig.xml

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` command,

```
awk 'NR==7{print "This is the new line"}7' filename
```

With `sed` command,

```
sed -i .bak '7i\
This is the new line\
' filename
```

these commands with insert **This is the new line**  at line number **7**.

Comment: OP wants to add a line, not replace it.